# ffmpeg concat only continues audio, not video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to concat 3 videos with ffmpeg. Here the code I use.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i c:/ffmpeg/data/mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

In my first try the first video played for the set time and then nothing more happened. There I tried to sync the audio and ran the following on all videos.

```
ffmpeg -i c:/ffmpeg/data/intro.mp4 -af apad -c:v copy -b:a 384k -shortest -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts intro.mp4
```

After running the concat again, now the audio from all 3 files play throughout the video, but only the video from the first video shows throughout the whole video.

I've tried to to get the video tracks in the same encoding with the following without any changed in th concat result.

```
ffmpeg -i c:/ffmpeg/data/video1.mp4 -r 24 video1.mp4
```

AND

```
ffmpeg -i c:/ffmpeg/data/video1.mp4 -af apad -c:v copy -b:v 64k -b:a 384k -shortest -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts video1.mp4
```

Here the ffprobe results for the 3 videos

*** FILE1 - INTRO ***

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mpeg4
codec_long_name=MPEG-4 part 2
profile=Simple Profile
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=9899/237568
codec_tag_string=mp4v
codec_tag=0x7634706d
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=1
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
quarter_sample=false
divx_packed=false
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24/1
avg_frame_rate=237568/9899
time_base=1/12288
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=118788
duration=9.666992
bit_rate=7558738
max_bit_rate=7558738
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=232
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=c:/ffmpeg/data/intro.mp4
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=9.667000
size=9135788
bit_rate=7560391
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2mp41
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.72.101
[/FORMAT]
```

*** FILE3 - VIDEO1 ***

```
    [STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/48
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=31
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24/1
avg_frame_rate=24/1
time_base=1/12288
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=470016
duration=38.250000
bit_rate=1550579
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=918
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=44100
channels=1
channel_layout=mono
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=1679328
duration=38.080000
bit_rate=70141
max_bit_rate=70141
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=1641
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=SoundHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=c:/ffmpeg/data/video1.mp4
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=38.250000
size=7778497
bit_rate=1626875
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.72.101
[/FORMAT]
```

*** FILE3 - OUTRO ***

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mpeg4
codec_long_name=MPEG-4 part 2
profile=Simple Profile
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=3115/74752
codec_tag_string=mp4v
codec_tag=0x7634706d
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=1
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
quarter_sample=false
divx_packed=false
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24/1
avg_frame_rate=74752/3115
time_base=1/12288
start_pts=565
start_time=0.045980
duration_ts=75325
duration=6.129964
bit_rate=3968655
max_bit_rate=3968655
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=146
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=268304
duration=6.083991
bit_rate=266855
max_bit_rate=384000
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=262
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=SoundHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=c:/ffmpeg/data/outro.mp4
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=6.084000
size=3226018
bit_rate=4241969
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2mp41
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.72.101
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: Show ffprobe readout for all three files.

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: Not the same codec or resolution. Re-encode to make them match.